# Java open html in background

Tags: java, html, browser

I want to open from my program multiple HTMLs. I do this by desktop.browse(), but it goes to my browser after opening every HTML. Is this a method to open HTML in background? For example I run my program it opening HTMLs and I can surfing the web at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by open HTML in background? Where do you store those open HTMLs?

Comment: *"multiple HTMLs."*  What URLs?  All pointing to one domain?  Do you control HTML at the end of the URLs?

Comment: I mean I click button search and program searches URLs, when it founds a record, it must be open immediately, but I don't want to show it. I'm clicking search, which takes about 5 minutes, in this time I want to do everything I want and I want to load find pages in this time in background. Now after finding any page I am switched to this page immediately. In background means the built in option in browser open in new tab in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring your application frame to front after opening html:

```
    mainFrame.toFront();
    mainFrame.repaint();
```

Comment: I don't want to bring mainFrame, I want to stay browser on page I'm looking at the opening new page moment.