# java open web page without focus

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome

I made a small program in java
is like a rss checker but when find something I launch this,

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(relHref));
```

But now I have a problem,
every time this event trigger i lose focus on the page/program. I wanna open the page without loosing it. Is this possible?

For instance: If I'm watching a movie and the event start i get the focus on the page and I have to stop/restart the movie.

This is almost the same problem i have 
[Java open html in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717509/java-open-html-in-background) but is without a solution :-(

Comment: This might be desktop environment and browser specific. Good to specify your environment. I don't see a method to select if other window should be back/foreground. So your option is to detect default browser yourself and launch it in another way to avoid focus stealing.

Comment: [google answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bDfp4KJ1DIc) i think this cannot be done?
[another](http://superuser.com/questions/704420/open-chrome-tab-in-background-using-command-line) 
i'm not the only one with this problem....